# Error en recursion en c

Tags: c

tengo un problema con la recursion, Estoy intentando que el usuario ingrese un numero y que en pantalla se muestren los números a partir de ese en forma descendente hasta el 1 en pantalla, es decir: 5, 4, 3, 2, 1

Agradecería si me pudieran explicar como funciona la solución a este problema ya que estoy aprendiendo recursion y se me está tornando complicado, gracias.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int lista(int n);

int main(){
    int i,numero;

    printf("Digite un numero: ");
    scanf("%d",&numero);

    for(i = numero;i > 0;i--){
        printf("%i.\n", lista(i));
    }

    return 0;   
}


int lista(int n){
    if(n == 1||n == 0){
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        return lista(n); 
    }
}
```

Comment: En tu caso, la función recursiva a) no tiene que devolver ningún valor (void), b) debe realizar la impresión del valor dentro de si misma, c) debe llamarse a si misma con (n - 1) como parámetro, o bien salir inmediatamente en caso de que el valor recibido sea 1.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<stdio.h>

void lista(int n); /* Función recursiva. Recibe el valor n introducido por
                    el usuario en la función "main()" */

int main(){

    int numero; /* Valor introducido por el usuario / inicio de la cuenta 
                 regresiva */

    printf("Dígito un numero: "); // Se pide el valor al usuario.
    scanf("%d",&numero);     // Guardamos el valor en la variable "numero"  
    lista(numero);           // Llamamos a la función recursiva.
 
    return 0;   
}

void lista(int n){
    if(n <= 1){     // Si el valor recibido es 1 o menor de 1 entonces: 
         printf("1.\n");    // Imprime 1.
    }else{                  // Si no:
        printf("%d.\n", n); // Imprime n.
        lista(n-1);  /* Llamamos a esta misma función de forma recursiva 
                      hasta que n sea menor o igual que 1. Para que esto 
                      se cumpla se llama a la función con n-1 para que se
                      pueda cumplir la condición de salida de la llamada 
                      recursiva. */
    }
}
```